# Disabling your Web Add-in if you have an Equivalent COM/VSTO Add-in doesn't work?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Like described in the feb 2021 community call I want to disable by web-addin by setting an equivalent com add-in. I update to the latest beta version (build 2103) and set all the registry key values, but does not seem to work.... What is the best way to check what is wrong? Can we debug? Any tips/examples of people that got this working?

PATH: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\addins\equivalentcomaddin
KEY (string/REG_SZ): {OfficeJS GUID}
VALUE: Prog.ID

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rick

Comment: Anyone? With such new feature, hope that MSFT will be available for support?

Comment: We are engaging at this topic: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1686

Answer (score 0):

Hey Rick to summarize the answer here:

1. Make sure you are on the latest Beta release.
2. if you are using the registry directly make sure to NOT use the curly braces for the GUID.
3. OR use the policy editor as described in https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1686